# Why we care about the topology of Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm reading Stillwell's Naive Lie Theory.

Seem it has two tracks:

- the Geometry and Analysis track, it sets up differentiation on Lie group, including Ch 1, 2, 4, 5, and 7.
- the Algebra and topology track investigates the topology properties of Lie groups with the help of algebra, this includes chap 3, 6, 8, and 9.

I can see the motivation of the geometry and analysis track, from quaternion and rotation, it defines exp and log functions, proved BCH theorem, then we can do differentiation on Lie algebra instead of Lie group, this is quite convenient. For example, in SLAM or Robot control, BCH helps on a first-order approximation.

But why would one be interested in the Topology track? Is it only for math purpose or there's application based on the topology knowledge of Lie group?

Comment: The theory of covering spaces is extremely relevant to the study of Lie groups, in particular for classifying all Lie groups having a given Lie algebra. There are other applications too, e.g. defining characteristic classes in algebraic topology.

Comment: The fact that $SU(2)$ is a double cover of $SO(3)$ is topological in nature but also implies that quantum spin is not invariant under a 360 degree rotation. You can see this is fundamentally topological because of the plate trick (belt trick, Dirac's string trick). This is why spinors are used to model intrinsic angular momentum. Topological properties can be falsifiable as well allowing to to test theory against reality. That can be useful.

Comment: Just for the record, your title is misleading because rarely is one interested in the topology of the Lie *algebras*: They are finite-dimensional vector spaces, and for most basic purposes, one does not need to consider any topology on them (although to be fair, for some structure theory e.g. the Zariski topology on them is useful). It is certainly topological properties of the Lie *group* which are crucial from very early on.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg indeed, i've updated the title